# Authenticating a user via wcf

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a java app with a .net application running in the java applications embedded browser.

I want the java application to call a .net WCF or web service with a username and password.

The wcf will set the user to authorized in forms authentication.

In the java desktop application I will then load a .aspx page that was protected via forms authentication.

How can I accomplish this?  Is it even possible...?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable ASP.NET compatibility mode on the WCF service in order to enable forms authentication.

The Java client application could send username and password over a secure connection and your WCF service authenticates the user via `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password)` or `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`.
You will then need to use a cookie store on the Java client side in order to pass the authentication cookie on every consecutive request (and update it when it gets refreshed), but this should be a built-in feature of your HTTP-client.

The .aspx page must run on a server with the same machine key as the WCF service.

Conclusion: Yes, it is possible, but for me it is not clear to which ".NET application" you refer to?

Edit: I think its clear now, you will need to be able to set the browser cookies. If you cant do this directly from your java application, a workaround would be to let the WCF service communicate that the user is authenticated and then set the cookie on the .aspx site request.